# jQuery Bootstrap From and To date validation

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been playing with bootstrap calendar.

I have used this date picker - http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/

My code looks like this. I was able to select the from and to date using the above docs/code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#datepicker.input-daterange').datepicker({
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
</script>
```

Now I would like to validate this jquery script.

Meaning: The user should be able to select *ANY* twelve months and it should not go beyond that.

In other words, *Apr-2013* to *Mar-2014* should be possible (since there are twelve months) and *Apr-2013* to *Apr-2014* should not be possible since it has 13 months in it and I need to throw an error message and ask the user to correct the From and To date.

Is there anything like this I can do with the above jQuery like:

```
length: "12m"
```

Please guide me. The user should be able to select **ANY YEAR** *(like Apr'2011 to Mar'2012)* but anything should be within 12 months.

Thanks,
Kimz

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the plugin "Date Range Picker for Twitter Bootstrap", it's fully configurable and has events you can use to validate the dates:

https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker

Answer (score 0):

I can see that there is an event [changeDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate) which is fired when date is changed. You can use that event to check your criteria as below.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on(changeDate, function(e){
       // check your criteria here
    });
```